# Are Solaris kernel stats unix:0:vopstats_zfs:* system (zpools) wide?

Tags: solaris, zfs

Are Solaris kernel stats `unix:0:vopstats_zfs:*` system (zpools) wide? I mean are those stats for all zpools present on system? I see sometimes huge differences between disks operations vs. ZFS operations and can't judge what makes that difference. For example ZFS write operations shows something between 2-3k operations per second, but disks shows more than 17k operations. On some periods those operations circa do match (if I take also L2ARC into account), but sometime they are totally divergent. I'm doing monitoring on global zone... is it possible, that something is hidden inside zones? It's one kernel so I expect same numbers in global zone and zones. System do have only ZFS, no UFS. No scrub was requested at that time.

Comment: This does not seem like a programming question. If it is, you should edit the question to provide a bit of background explaining how. Some other SE site might be better fit (http://unix.stackexchange.com maybe).

Comment: Correct, mea cupla... can you transfer to Unix or server fault?

Comment: No, I can't. Flag for moderator attention yourself, or just delete this since it has no answers, and ask at different site (a word of warning: you don't want to do *too many* deletes in too short time, or you may get a penalty like question ban, but one every now and then is perfectly fine). Another note, you might want to split the text into more than one paragraph, to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what Solaris release you are using.

From Solaris 11 onward, file system statistics are reported per zone while they are reported globally with Solaris 10 and older.

`unix:0:vopstats_zfs:*` only report the global zone activity.

`unix:xx:vopstats_zfs:*` will report the statistics for the zone with id `xx`.

You do not state if you parse the `kstat(1M)` command line output or if you use the `libkstat` API. Note that you can use the `-z zone` or `-Z` (all zones) `fsstat` [options](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29024/gmheh.html) through the CLI.